# How to use Routes inside a sub-component ? React Routes

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying make the following React App:

```
App.tsx
|__ Router -> '/' => MainComponent

MainComponent.tsx
|__ Route -> '/comp1/child1' => Child1
|__ Route -> '/subcomp2' => SubComponent2

SubComponent2.tsx
|__ Route -> '/subcomp2/child1' => Child1
|__ Route -> '/subcomp3' => SubComponent3
```

And so on.

When the app redirects to component, the loaded component redirect automatically to Child (a component inside the loaded component), then by trigger the app redirects to other component.

Well, the problem is, of course, this didn't work at all. Just the App.tsx to MainComponent.tsx works.
When I change the redirect to 'subcomp2', the routes inside not work.

My questions are:
this is possible using Routes?.
Can I set routes inside a subcomponents?.
Is something I'm doing wrong?

An example what I have:

```
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/">
                    <MainComponent/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }


class MainComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    render(){return(
        <Fragment>
            <Route path='/comp1/child1'>
                <Child1 />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/comp2'>
                <Component2 />
            </Route>
        </Fragment>
    );}
}
export default withRouter(MainComponent);

class Component2 extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    render(){return(
        <Fragment>
            <Route path='/comp2/child1'>
                <Child1 />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/comp3'>
                <Component3 />
            </Route>
        </Fragment>
    );}
}
export default withRouter(Component2);

class Component3 extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    render(){return(
        <Fragment>
            <Route path='/comp3/child1'>
                <Child1 />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/comp4'>
                <Component4 />
            </Route>
        </Fragment>
    );}
}
export default withRouter(Component3);
```

Saludos y Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routing architecture needs some modifications, for example when you load the route **/**, this route will load the component **MainComponent**, and the **child component** will not be loaded because in order to load it the current route must be **/comp1/child1** not **/**, so the solution you need to modify route for your child component like this: **/**.

```
MainComponent.tsx 
|__ Route -> '/' => Child1 
|__ Route -> '/subcomp2' => SubComponent2
```

//Also here, we have an issue

```
SubComponent2.tsx
 |__ Route -> '/subcomp2/child1' => Child1
 |__ Route -> '/subcomp3' => SubComponent3 //this route will not work
```

The route **/subcomp3** will not work because in order to load the component SubComponent2 the active route must start with **subcomp2** so the route of
SubComponent3 must be  **/subcomp2/subcomp3**

the correct one:

```
SubComponent2.tsx
 |__ Route -> '/subcomp2' => Child1
 |__ Route -> '/subcomp2/subcomp3' => SubComponent3 //this will not work
```

Also, you need to add wrap you routes inside **Switch** component, because for example here:

```
|__ Route -> '/' => Child1 
|__ Route -> '/subcomp2' => SubComponent2
```

when the active route is **/**, this will load the component **child1** and **SubComponent2**

```
 function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/">
                    <MainComponent/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }


class MainComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    render(){return(
        <Fragment>
           <Switch>
            <Route path='/comp2'> //must be first
                <Component2 />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/'>
                <Child1 />
            </Route>
           </Switch>
        </Fragment>
    );}
}
export default withRouter(MainComponent);

class Component2 extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    render(){return(
        <Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/comp2/comp3'>
                <Component3 />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/comp2'>
                <Child1 />
            </Route>
           </Switch>
        </Fragment>
    );}
}
export default withRouter(Component2);

class Component3 extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
    render(){return(
        <Fragment>
           <Switch>
            <Route path='/comp2/comp3/comp4'>
                <Component4 />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/comp2/comp3'>
                <Child1 />
            </Route>
         </Switch>
        </Fragment>
    );}
}
export default withRouter(Component3);
```

Comment: Hi capo, thanks, this works like a flame. But, the Components can be mixed up, for example, Component5 have a Route to Component3, they are not sequenced.
Is a good practice pass as prop the current route "/compN" and use it for create the others routes?.
Component 5 (this.props.basepath= "Comp5")
|__ Route -> {`${this.props.basepath}/comp3`} => <Component 3 basepath={`${this.props.basepath}/comp3`} />

Comment: I think your solution is more dynamic, I have a note here <Component3 basepath={${this.props.basepath}/comp3} />  you don't need to pass the route as props because you can get it via this.props.basepath. If you find the answer helpful, plz check it:)

Answer (score 0):

Define all your routes in the App component.

```
    function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/">
                    <MainComponent/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/comp1/child1">
                    <Child1 />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/comp2">
                    <Component2 />
                </Route> // ... and so on
            </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser amego.
Question, is it mandatory?, it cannot be in different components?. 
I want to use a "public component" as Router for their children components.